# Office Word и С# .NET

Tags: c#, ms-word

Есть некий doc файл в котором хранится шаблон документа(должен быть заполнен с формы). Но когда программа пытается что то записать в этот doc - то он переходит в режим "Только для чтения" и следовательно программа ни чего не может в нем изменить.

Метод `Open` (проходит отлично):

```
doc = app.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref trueValue,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Метод `Execute`(в нем я ищу слово которое надо заменить `findText` и меняю на `replaceWith`. И вот тут он мне выдает ошибку - "данная команда не доступна")

```
app.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref replaceWith,
            ref replace, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задал диапазон поиска через

`Range wordRange = doc.Sections[i].Range;`

Потом сделал массив с параметрами

```
Find wordFindObj = wordRange.Find;

object[] wordFindParameters = new object[15] { strToFindObj, missingObj, missingObj, missingObj, missingObj, missingObj, missingObj, missingObj, missingObj, replaceStrObj, replaceTypeObj, missingObj, missingObj, missingObj, missingObj };
```

Потом вызвал Find

```
wordFindObj.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, wordFindObj, wordFindParameters);
```